# iPhone: time from CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, timestamp

I am using  a `CLLocationManager` to get the current location of the an iPod/iPhone.  The delegate that I implement has this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
```

I have a couple questions about the timestamp value of a `CLLocation` returned from this method.

For example when I print: `startingLocation.timestamp` this time will look like this: `2010-11-39 20:57:19 GMT`.

1. Am I guaranteed that the time stamp will be `GMT`?
2. Where is the device getting this time stamp?  If it is getting GPS locational data will this be the time stamp fromt he GPS?  (That would be very accurate and consistent between devices).  If the user has weird time settings on their device will this affect the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp is an `NSDate` object, which represents an abstract moment in time and has no particular time zone or calendar system associated with it. When you use a logging command, it's  converting its internal value to GMT to make it human-readble, but that doesn't mean it's a GMT date. You can convert its internal value into any calendar or timezone you want via the `NSCalendar` and `NSDateFormatter` classes.

Apple gives no reason to assume the timestamp is derived from GPS. Its purpose is to tell you the age of the location reading, so logically it would be stamped from the system time, otherwise you wouldn't be able to reliably calculate its age (or compare its age with non-GPS readings).  You could do some testing to find out for sure.

Comment: since the time stamp is an *"abstract moment in time and has no particular time zone or calendar system associated with it"*, what are you supposed to compare it with to tell how old it is?

Comment: +[NSDate date], which is the current system time in the same format. Check the NSDate documentation for the various methods for comparing them or extracting a more conventional date.